# How to pass a string to a layout in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm just starting out with Android so please bear with me.
I have a layout file (below) that has a text view. I also have an activity that passes a String message to the new activity, all that works fine. What I am trying to do is pass that message to the layout instead of doing this:

```
// Create the text view
   TextView textView = new TextView(this);
   textView.setTextSize(40);
   textView.setText(message);
```

My understanding is that I want all the layout code in an xml layout file not in my Java code.

My Layout file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.mycompany.myapplication.DisplayMessageActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/messageTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Code for my activity.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    //Create the text view
    TextView messageTextView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);
    messageTextView.setText(message);

    //Set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(messageTextView);

    //Set back button
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


}
```

When I run the code my main activity works i get a simple text field with a button. I type my message and hit send. Then the application crashes. Before I changed the code to attempt and display the message in a layout file, I was rendering the code with:

```
// Create the text view
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setTextSize(40);
textView.setText(message);
```

And that worked fine. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call   `setContentView(messageTextView);` before you try to access your layout. That way your activity will have access to your layout.

Therefore, your onCreate should look like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(messageTextView);

    //Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    //Create the text view
    TextView messageTextView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);
    messageTextView.setText(message);

    //Set back button
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for posting a duplicate question.